# How to crawl a specific div tag to get all data inside that?

Tags: php, xpath, web-crawler

Actually i'm new to PHP and I want to crawl [this](http://www.phonebook.com.pk/Dynamic/Search.aspx?k=courier&l=pakistan&SearchType=kl) link to get info about all courier companies providing services in our country. All the info that i required are insid a div tag i.e. . I need all info inside this tag with Images, paragraphs and links. I've done some research on that and able to crawl the page.

```
     <?php
        function crawl_page($url, $depth = 1)
        {
            static $seen = array();
            if (isset($seen[$url]) || $depth === 0) {
                return;
            }
        
            $seen[$url] = true;
        
            $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
            @$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
        
            $xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
            $divTag = $xpath->query('//div[@class="rescont"]');
    
foreach ($divTag as $val) {
            echo $dom->saveXML($val).'<br />\n';// or 
          }
  }
    crawl_page("http://www.phonebook.com.pk/Dynamic/Search.aspx?k=courier&l=pakistan&SearchType=kl", 1);

  ?>
```

**EDit:**
Now i'm able to display all contents on my webpage but images and some other info is not available because it was linked as relative to that server. Can i extract that info too?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by _some other info_?

Comment: Let suppose i want to crawl all <td> tags inside that div